# With Swift Package Manager, how to update Firebase SDK version?

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

My Firebase SDK is showing version 9.6.0, but I want to update to a newer version, such as 10.6.0.

I've tried the dropdown menu "Update Package" by right clicking on the dependency, but nothing happens.

[image]

I've also tried Packages->Update to Latest Package Versions, still nothing happens.

So what exactly should I do to update the version from 9.6.0 -> some newer version available? Should I do something here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Project page, and from Package Dependencies, double click on the package , then choose `Exact` and input the version you want.

[image]

And that's it, after click Done, XCode will update the package to the version you specify.

Comment: Did you actually try this? I did. Doesn't work. Good generic answer about SPM in general. But WRT to THIS EXACT PACKAGE, no, this answer does not address the issue. According to GitHub they are up to 10.7.0 - but SPM only goes up to 9.6.0. WHY?

Comment: I actually tried it and my package is now at 10.6.0. If you don't specify exact version, it goes to 9.6.0, probably because it is the major stable version. But if you specify "Exact" version, you can go to the version you want. I answered my own question, this is exactly the solution I was trying to find.